# Oracle APEX Shuttle Box Output

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am new to APEX, and I am having issues with displaying output. The shuttle box itself works fine, but below it I have a submit button. When this is pressed it should display the user's manager in the region below. This is what I have so far, but I am not sure whether it is my code or some other setting in APEX that I am missing:

```
`DECLARE
 I_selected APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
 BEGIN
 FOR i IN 1..apex_application.g_f01.count
 LOOP
  if apex_application.g_f01(i) is not null then
 begin
 SELECT DISTINCT MANAGER_ID
 Where USERID = apex_application.g_f02(i);
 FROM au.RECERTIFICATION
 WHERE USERID = :I_selected;
 COMMIT;
 end if;
 END LOOP;
 Return APEX_UTL.TABLE_TO_STRING (I_selected);
 END;`
```

Comment: This is for the button click event by the way.

Comment: This code, where is it? A process? It can't parse, it has several syntax errors. Why do you mention a shuttle and how is this relevant to showing the user's manager? Is the "user" the actual application user?

Answer (score 1):

The basic Apex shuttle control will hold a single string value which will be a concatenation of the selected values separated by colons (:), e.g. `'JONES:SMITH:BLOGGS'`.

In your event processing you could use it like this:

```
FOR r IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT MANAGER_ID
  FROM au.RECERTIFICATION
  WHERE INSTR(':' || :shuttleitem || ':', ':' || USERID || ':') > 0
  ) LOOP
  -- do something with r.manager_id
END LOOP;
```

Note: make sure that the values for your shuttle item's list cannot have any embedded colons (:).